# XPath - How to get parent node from undetermined depth

Tags: xml, xpath

Let us assume I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root identifier="m1">
  <orgs default="toc00001">
    <org identifier="toc00001">
      <item identifier="itm00012">
        <title>aaa</title>
        <item identifier="a123">
          <title>bbbb</title>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item identifier="itm00001">
        <title>Some text</title>
        <item identifier="itm00027">
          <title>Something</title>
          <item identifier="itm00028">
            <title>Another text</title>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </org>
  </orgs>
</root>
```

I have a node with identifier `itm00028` at my disposal in the code. I would like to get the parent item (the one directly below org node) using `xpath 1.0`.

Something like:

```
//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/ancestor::item/some other condition
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the suggested responses are what I want.

`//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/ancestor::item[1]` assumes I need to know beforehand the depth. I stated in the question that depth can be arbitrary, from 1 to large number.

`//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/ancestor::org/item` is incorrect because it retrieves the first child item node. I need the node that actually contains the item I am starting with.

`//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/../../item[1]/title` again assuming fixed structure of the xml.

This is what I need:

```
//org/item[descendant::item[@identifier="itm00028"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually get the `org` first and then get the item:

```
//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/ancestor::org/item
```

So you make sure which want you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/../../item[1]/title
```

and also from previous comment:

```
//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/ancestor::item[1]/title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ancestor::org/child::item[.//item[@identifier = 'itm00028']]
```

or

```
//item[@identifier="itm00028"]/ancestor::org/child::item[.//item[@identifier = 'itm00028']]
```

Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: `//org/item[descendant::item[@identifier="itm00028"]]` this is what works for me